# Figma - Gradient over multiple elements

Tags: gradient, figma

How can I make a gradient over multiple element in Figma? As much as I know you can only make a gradient over one element or let's say select multiple but then the gradient doesn't go over all, it just starts off on every single element.

Thanks for your answers^^

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select multiple objects and do *Object > Flatten Selection*. Now you should be able to add a gradient fill that spans all the objects.

Example

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly :D

Comment: This doesn't solve for most of my issues. Once you flatten an object, you can no longer modify it. To modify it, you have to separate each shape. Once you do that, you lose the stretch gradient. There has to be some issue with mask but I forget.